# How to connect Pusher client to Heroku in iOS

Tags: ios, heroku

How to connect Pusher client to heroku environment.

```
  self.client = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:PusherAppKey delegate:self encrypted:YES];
 _client.authorizationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"XXXXX.com"];

[self.client connect];
self.channel = [_client subscribeToChannelNamed:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
[self.client bindToEventNamed:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXX" target:self action:@selector(handleNewMessageEvent:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I resolved it by doing

```
self.client = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:PusherAppKey delegate:self encrypted:NO];
```